# Best way to match and catch doubly-entified character entities/references?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, character-entities

I'm talking about stuff like `&amp;amp;` which will then render to: `&amp;` when it actually should render to `&`.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566098/what-are-the-longest-and-shortest-html-character-entity-names#comment16927915_12566098) I asked how to match entities, but it seems that isn't really possible or realistic with regexes.  What then is the best way to match double entities?

**EDIT:** Is this a good way to do it? `.replace(/&amp;(?=#?x?[0-9a-z]+);/i, '&');`

(I'm using javascript)

Comment: Use a html parser. Google for them in your technology (java, php etc)

Comment: Javascript. And I need to stay lightweight. Not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
 pattern       &([a-zA-Z0-9]+?;)\1
 replacement   &$1
```

to replace just double amps, or:

```
 pattern       &amp;([#a-zA-Z0-9]+?;)
```

EDIT:

your pattern

```
 /&amp;(?=#?x?[0-9a-z]+);/i
```

looks also good to me.

Note: none of these is something you can trust

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
&amp;[a-zA-Z]+;
```

Though not fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your data first. Use whatever you know about encoding to decode them back to form where character/piece of data have only one possible encoding. After that match this normalized data with normalized pattern.